# Chrome Browser : SSL connection error

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I followed this website 
http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/11/securing-tomcat.html
to create a self signed keystore certificte 
nd finally  installed it to  tomcat

Now , to make Tomcat SSL enabled i modified the
[CATALINA_HOME]\conf\server.xml

This is the entry i added

```
<Connector  port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" 
               minSpareThreads="25" 
               maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" 
               disableUploadTimeout="true"
               acceptCount="100" 
               scheme="https" 
               secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" 
               sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="keystore.jks" 
               keystorePass="kiran123"/>
```

Now when i tried to access the Application which is running under the tomcat server , the google chrome browser gave me this error

SSL connection error

Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

Comment: This is a generic error. Please put the link so people can send responses and check the error in more details.